# IIS 6.0 and Webservices

Tags: web-services, iis, iis-6

I'm hesitating in the choice of the configuration my webservices in IIS.

So the first choice is : creating a virtual site for each webservice in IIS
the second choice is : create a global virtual site and for each webservice i create a virtual directory

Ps : I'm using IIS 6.0

Comment: It doesn't matter. Why would you think it matters at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there will be a direct answer for this. I think you should take a few things in consideration. First you should consider if these services are logically related. It can be a good practice to group similar or somehow related services in the same virtual site. Second concern is maintenance. If you put all services in the same virtual site it can be difficult to reconfigure in the future if services need to be configured again with different virtual site settings.

Comment: Thanks for your responses ! I thougt there was an ideal solution but it depends on the developped system.

Comment: You are welcome. if they will have all same virtual site settings, putting them all in same virtual site will make it more easy to reconfigure.